# Welcome Page Add to Favorites

Tags: delphi, ide

I am using Delphi 2010.  Has the functionality on the Welcome Page to Add to Favorites been eliminated?  I still have Manage Favorites, but it only adds Edit and Delete options.  Maybe there is a new way to add to favorites now.  I missed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just click on the link marked "Make me a Favorite":

[image]

Comment: hahaha, you beat me again, why I bother to hide the project names? hahaha. :)

Comment: Well, I always give a +1 to the winner, so here it is!

Comment: @David +1, also.. I really miss a bottom text box which says "David is writing...", it will make me hurry when writing a new anser :) hahahaha. :D

Comment: @jachguate: Indeed, @David is the Jon Skeet of the Delphi tag.

Comment: Doh!  The first two projects on my Welcome Page were already favorites.  I did not see that the link was there on the ones that were not favorites.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Andreas LOL, I never heard before of that guy, but I'm with you about @David... hahahaha. :)

Comment: Priceless thanks ! Just spend 10 minutes trying to find out how to do it. In the end I had to come to this page :)

Answer (score 4):

It is named *Make me a Favorite* now

[image]

Comment: +1 for both the correct answer and for the "David is writing..." comment to David's post above. <g>